# How to implement API composition in NGINX?

Tags: node.js, api, nginx, microservices, composition

I haven't found a way to implement API Composition using nginx,

the architecture am trying to get working looks like this:
[image]

Link: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/api-composition.html

the goal is from one endpoint, call multiple endpoints behind it;

localhost:3000 -> [localhost:5000, localhost:6000, localhost:7000]

and have one response

Comment: This is just reverse proxying. You're probably not using the right term to search. First of all, in the industry this is not called API composition but an API Gateway. Secondly, API gateway is not a functionality of web servers like Apache or Nginx (though Nginx does sell a special API Gateway version of their software). It is how us use it. The functionality is called "Reverse Proxy"

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Using the documentation you provided, i will be able to only route one http request to one service, what am looking for is not routing using paths hence "API Gateway", am looking for a way to gather responses from multiples services, in  a response to one http call, maybe i didn't explain myself well, but here is the link to the concept: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/api-composition.html

Comment: The keyword in there docs: in-memory join of the results.

Comment: nginx can't join multiple results.

Comment: Nginx isn't a proper tool for that. You can still use Node though

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do this with nginx. You'll have to build your own "composer" or use a different tool.

If you want a tool specifically for this purpose, you may want to look at [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/).